# Cannot add buttons to table view toolbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

So I have a root view with table view. I display the toolbar like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;
}
```

And I implement the setToolbarItems method:

```
- (void)setToolbarItems:(NSArray *)toolbarItems animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    UIBarButtonItem *buttonItem;
    buttonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(goBack:)];
    self.navigationController.toolbarItems = [ NSArray arrayWithObject: buttonItem ];
}
```

The result is an empty tolbar. Why?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

> toolbarItems
> The toolbar items associated with the view controller.
>
> @property(nonatomic, retain) NSArray *toolbarItems
> Discussion
> This property contains an array of UIBarButtonItem objects and works in >conjunction with a UINavigationController object. If this view controller is >embedded inside a navigation controller interface, and the navigation >controller displays a toolbar, this property identifies the items to display in >that toolbar.
>
> You can set the value of this property explicitly or use the >setToolbarItems:animated: method to animate changes to the visible set of >toolbar items.

In other words, try accessing it through the actual view controller, not it's navigation controller like so:

```
self.toolbarItems = [ NSArray arrayWithObject: buttonItem ];
```

Answer (score 1):

But who calls your implementation of setToolbarItems?

You're supposed to *call* setToolbarItems on your own view, not re-implement it.  Then, the NavigationController will find them in the instance variable and render them.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;

    UIBarButtonItem *buttonItem;
    buttonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(goBack:)];
    [self setToolbarItems: [ NSArray arrayWithObject: buttonItem ]];
}
```